# onDestroy isn't called on stopSelf() in service

Tags: android, service

I am starting a service from a broardcast receiver like this:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, BarometricLogger.class);
context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

When I have finished doing the Work I am calling my cleanUp() method (it is from the service):

```
private void cleanUp()
{
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorListener);
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    isLocationSet = false;

    isClean = true;

    this.stopSelf();
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't look like the service is stopped because onDestroy() isn't called! What am I doing wrong?

BR

Comment: There is no onStop() in the service

Comment: Oh..yes...have you binded your service anywhere else ? or you can check with IntentService too..as they would stop itself after finishing the job.

Comment: I don't have any bindings. At least I don't use the Word - so I don't think so. I am also starting the service from an alarm with an pending intent. What do you meen by: "...check with IntentService too..."?

Comment: Use IntentService rather than Service ,since it would stop itself , when It is done with it's job .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ooops... that's almost embarrassing. It didn't stop because I accidentally put it into a never ending loop... :S